# Como obtener una linea impar e impar en una tabla de multiplicar en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, bucle-for, condiciones, else

Hola necesito ayuda en este problema, es que no se como resolverle, ya llevo bastante tiempo intentándolo y he llegado a la desesperación. Creo que el problema esta en el if y en el else.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>

     </head>
        <body>
                          <script type= "text/javascript">
    numero = prompt("Introduce un número: ");
    window.onload = function(){
    
     document.write("<h2>TABLA DE MULTIPLICAR DE "+numero+"</h2>");
    
        document.write("<table border='1'><tr><td>Número</td><td>Factor</td><td>Resultado</td></tr>");
            for(i%2==0; i <=10;i++){
            
             if (i % 2==0) {
                             // filas pares
                style.backgroundColor = "red";
            } else {
                             // filas impares
                style.backgroundColor = "green";
            }
                
                document.write("<tr><td>"+numero+" </td><td> " + i +"</td><td>" + numero * i + "</td></tr>");
            }
        document.write("</table>");
    }
                
                </script>   
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: hola listo ya arregle los errores en la sintaxis y también ya quite mi nombre, gracias a los dos :).

Comment: ahora porfa ayúdenme :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ponlo así mejor:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Ejercicio 18_3</title>
  </head>

  <body>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
  numero = prompt("Introduce un número: ");
  document.write("<h2>TABLA DE MULTIPLICAR DE " + numero + "</h2>");
  document.write("<table border='1'><tr><td>Número</td><td>Factor</td><td>Resultado</td></tr>");
  for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    let fondo
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      // filas pares
      fondo = "red";
    } else {
      // filas impares
      fondo = "green";
    }
    document.write("<tr style='background-color:" + fondo + "'><td>" + numero + " </td><td> " + i + "</td><td>" + numero * i + "</td></tr>");
  }
  document.write("</table>");
}
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

### Explicación de los cambios

- He cambiado esto:

```javascript
for(i%2==0; i <=10;i++){
```

por esto:

```javascript
for(i=0; i <=10;i++){
```

para que se hagan los 10 ciclos del bucle que deseas de la tabla de multiplicar. Lo anterior no tenia sentido.

- He inicializado una variable denominada **fondo** que luego usaremos para almacenar el valor del color en cada ciclo del bucle

```javascript
let fondo
```

- He cambiado esto, que no tenia sentido y provocaba que el script no funcionara:

```javascript
style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

por esto:

```javascript
fondo = 'red'
```

para almacenar ese color en la variable, que usaremos a continuación

- He cambiado esto:

```javascript
document.write("<tr>
```

por esto:

```javascript
document.write("<tr style='background-color:" + fondo + "'>
```

para que cuando usemos **fondo** estemos aplicándolo en el estilo del color de fondo de toda la fila gracias al atributo `style='background-color:" + fondo + "'`

Comment: mil gracias :D!!!

Comment: De nada, aunque los agradecimientos se hacen aceptando las respuestas que han sido útiles a tu pregunta. En este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y así no dejar preguntas eternamente pendientes en este sitio.  También léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento de este sitio y cómo realizar buenas preguntas y así pasar a colaborar con el. Gracias

Comment: Está bien el cambio del document.write, pero para evitar el lío de comillas y concatenaciones se podría usar un string template -> `document.write(\`<tr style="background-color:${fondo}">\`);`

Comment: lo siento chicos por las molestias, es que nose usar muy bien la plataforma, pero creo que ya he aceptado la respuesta.

Comment: Perecto @Juan, ahora sí! :-)  Gracias por contribuir al buen funcionamiento del sitio. Y aprender como funciona este sitio es tan fácil como perder dos minutos de tu vida leyéndote el [tour] y además así te darán una medalla más si llegas a leer hasta el final!! (mira que gustan las medallas, lucen mucho! xD)